# Unresolved Reference getResources() Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-arrayadapter, custom-arrayadapter

So I am trying to access the getResources() in my code, but for some reason it keeps getting an unresolved reference. I am doing this in another class for my array adapter. Is it because I don't have a main method or is it because of other reasons? I am bit new to android dev and kotlin in general so any help would be appreciate it.

```js
class ForecastAdapter(val forecast: Forecast) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ForecastData>(){
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return forecast.list.count()

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): ForecastData {
        val layoutInflator = LayoutInflater.from(p0?.context)
        val cellForRow = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.weather_row, p0, false)
        return ForecastData(cellForRow)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: ForecastData, p1: Int) {
        val drawableId: Int = getResources().getIdentifier("my_drawable", "drawable", getPackageName())
        val getWeather = forecast.list[p1]
        val clouds = getWeather.weather[0]
        val getDateTime = forecast.list[p1]
        var getIcon = forecast.list[p1]
        var icon = getIcon.weather[0]
        p0.view.textView_text_clouds.text = clouds.main
        p0.view.textView_date_time.text = getDateTime.dt_txt

    }

}

class ForecastData(val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){


}
```

Comment: you need `context` here for correct reference  like `viewHolder.itemView.context.resources`

`p0.itemView.context.resources` in your case

Comment: `[this.]getResources()` is a method that exists when you extend a class that is a `Context` for example `Activity` or has a reference internally e.g. `View`. A `RecyclerView.Adapter` does not inherit this method so you'll need a reference to some external `Context` object. Either do what @sasikumar suggests and to require an explicit reference in the constructor or use the `View` objects you are given as method arguments like above comment suggests.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pass context as parameter in your adapter then use like this

```
 class ForecastAdapter(val forecast: Forecast,val context:Context)
```

then

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: ForecastData, p1: Int) {
    val drawableId: Int = context.getResources().getIdentifier("my_drawable", "drawable", getPackageName())
```

Comment: Okay and then I would pass it in like this when calling the class?
`view.adapter = ForecastAdapter(weather, context)` When I do pass it in like that it says unresolved reference

Comment: @ZubairAmjad `view.adapter = ForecastAdapter(weather, this)` when you do that in an `Activity`. Or `view.adapter = ForecastAdapter(weather, activity!!)` ([`getActivity()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getActivity())) if you're doing that from a `Fragment`

Comment: When I do this though, it says it wants context, but I assume this would point to context?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to pass it through the constructor. 
In the onCreateViewHolder you can take it from the **parent.context**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the root. context from the view.

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: ForecastData, p1: Int) {
        val drawableId: Int = p0.view.root.context.resources.getIdentifier("my_drawable", 

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use ContextCompat.

```
ContextCompat.getColor(this.applicationContext, android.R.color.transparent)
```